# redirect ssl to non ssl

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, http-status-code-301

I am trying to rediret from ssl back to non ssl in apache and I am not having any luck. Can this be done via htaccess?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.mydomain.org
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Enable logging with the RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel directives, it will show you what it's doing.

Comment: So everything looks ok from the htaccess rules it is maybe a server configuration issue then?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your .htaccess file under DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteRule . http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hmm, can you show me Apache's access.log for this request pls?

Answer (score 0):

First of all; is your website running properly on HTTPS? if yes; then given code should work properly to redirect from HTTPS to http version.